# How to get S3 object url after it's been uploaded to a bucket using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a file which needs to be uploaded to an s3 bucket which has public read access.

I need to use that s3 object's url somewhere else after uploading the file.

How do I get the url of the s3 object after it's been uploaded to the bucket?

I'm using aws-cli to upload the file:

```
aws s3 cp local_file s3_location
```

I'm looking probably for something like `https://s3_bucket-region.amazonaws.com/folder/filename.format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the URL [Path-style access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro), you have all the information.

```
https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key name
```

> In this example, my-bucket is the bucket name, US West (Oregon) is the Region, and puppy.png is the key name

```
https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/puppy.png
```

`NOTE`: path-style URLs style will be deprecated soon.